# is it possible to get an input onto a variable while having it in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get this function into a while loop but am having trouble with it. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
def get_totalspent():
    print("Please enter the amount you spent on coffee for each day of the week\n")
    weekdays = ["sunday","monday","Tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]
    sunday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for sunday:"))
    monday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for monday:"))
    tuesday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for tuesday:"))
    wednesday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for wednesday:"))
    thursday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for thursday:"))
    friday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for friday:"))
    saturday=eval(input("Enter amount spent for saturday:"))

    #accumulate total
    totalSpent = sunday+monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday+saturday
    print("You spent:", totalSpent, "dollars on coffee this week. You may want to cut back on the caffine!")
```

Comment: What does "having trouble with it" means ? Error ? Unexpected result ? You need to give us information so that we have facts to help you.

Comment: Arrays, lists, dictionaries - collection objects are your friend :) You may also consider the question in this way: *how can I make this function work for any day?*

Comment: Please add the complete code with your attempt and values you used in your test so we can look at and analyze it with working code.

Comment: "eval" is dangerous. If you want to convert a string consisting of a float value to a float, use "float(input(...".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to define many variables. Instead, you can use a list:

```py
weekdays = ["sunday","monday","Tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"]

amounts = []
for day in weekdays:
    amounts.append(float(input(f"Enter amount spent for {day}: ")))

print(f"You spent ${sum(amounts):.2f}.")
```

Comment: What is the question that you're answering, if I may ask?

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Well I thought the OP was having trouble with dynamically assigning values to many variables in a (hypothetical) `while` loop. Maybe I should have confirmed it.